# What is a DOM path?

Tags: dom

Searching the web for `DOM path` returns results that lack a consensus, are about XPath, or altogether have nothing to do with technology. There are questions on Stack Overflow that ask about DOM paths, but there is no indication of a "DOM path" being the same thing to different people (in the same way things like HTMLor integers are conceived of the same way).

What is a DOM path? What makes for a valid DOM path? What are they used with?

Comment: In what context? Generally, I would think it would just be the edges leading from the root to a given element.

Answer (score 2):

A so called `DOM Path` is not definied by the DOM specification itself. The closest thing you can find there, are [event paths](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#event-path).

An event path is definied as follows:

> An event has an associated path. A path is a list of structs. Each
>   struct consists of an item (an EventTarget object), an
>   item-in-shadow-tree (a boolean), a target (a potential event target),
>   a relatedTarget (a potential event target), a touch target list (a
>   list of potential event targets), a root-of-closed-tree (a boolean),
>   and a slot-in-closed-tree (a boolean). A path is initially the empty
>   list.